# Error on insertion of data after successful opening of connection

Tags: database

I'm inserting data from mysql table to postgres table and my code is:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table

from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker

import psycopg2

class TestTable(object):

    pass

class StoreTV(object):

    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    engine = create_engine('mysql://root@localhost:3306/irt', echo=False)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    metadata = MetaData(engine)
    test_table = Table('test_1', metadata, autoload=True)

    store_tv_table = Table('roku_store', metadata, autoload=True)

    mapper(TestTable, test_table)
    mapper(StoreTV, store_tv_table)

    res = session.query(TestTable).all()
    print res[1].test_1col

    tv_list = session.query(StoreTV).all()

    for tv in tv_list:
        tv_data = dict()
        tv_data = {
            'title': tv.name,
            'email': tv.business_email
        }
        print tv_data


        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="db", user="user", password="pass", host="localhost", port="5432")
        print "Opened database successfully"
        cur = conn.cursor()
        values = cur.execute("Select * FROM iris_store")
        print values
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO iris_store(title, business_email) VALUES ('title':tv_data[title], 'business_email':tv_data[business_email])")
        print "Record created successfully"

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

And I'm not able to get data from postgres data and insert into postgres table 
while I'm successful to get data from Mysql table

ERROR is:

> something
>
> {'email': 'name@example.com', 'title': "Some Name"}
>
> Opened database successfully
>
> None
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/Desktop/porting.py", line 49, in 
>      cur.execute("INSERT INTO iris_store(title, business_email) VALUES ('title':tv_data[title], 'business_email':tv_data[business_email])")
>
> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ":"
>   LINE 1: ... iris_store(title, business_email) VALUES ('title':tv_data[t...
>                                                               ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usman 
you have to check your data type for email to insert data.
because to insert data from mysql to postgres you have to both fields of same type.
[click here and page no 28 will describe you aboout the data types of mysql and postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/2/23/Pgconfde-2011-mysql-to-pg-print.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you hava a sql syntax error in your insert query. It should look something like this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO iris_store(title, business_email) VALUES (%(title)s, %(email)s)", tv_data)
```

For reference, see: [Passing parameters to SQL queries](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters)

Also you probably don't want to create a new connection to your postgres db for each single value in `tv_list`, you should move the connect and close calls outside of the `for` loop, and printing the whole table each time also doesn't seem very useful

Comment: This time i am getting this error:
 File "/home/usmanmaqbool/Desktop/porting.py", line 49, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO iris_store(title, business_email) VALUES (%(title)s, %(email)s)", tv_data)
psycopg2.DataError: array value must start with "{" or dimension information
LINE 1: ...re(title, business_email) VALUES ('Naeem''s Biz', 'naeem.ily...

Comment: I removed ('s) from my table
then on execution i got this error:
cur.execute("INSERT INTO iris_store(title, business_email) VALUES (%(title)s, %(email)s)", tv_data)
psycopg2.DataError: array value must start with "{" or dimension information
LINE 1: ...store(title, business_email) VALUES ('Naeem Biz', 'naeem.ily...

Comment: finally i got my error:
error was because of data type for the email column.
Thanks @mata